# android studio tool that spots duplicate or similar parts of code?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a chunk of code about 1200 lines of code in my Activity. Is there a tool that watches through my code and finds some similar duplicate code that can be put in one method?
Like this:

```
onCreate(){
  image1.startAnimation(am1) ;
  image2.startAnimation(am1) ;

  .....
  image1.startAnimation(am1) ;
  image2.startAnimation(am1) ;

}
```

I want to put same code in one method, is there way to automatically spot duplicate codes?

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ is able to detect duplicate code by running a [static analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/analyzing-duplicates.html), but this tool is not yet available in Android Studio. Hopefully it will be added sooner or later.

In the meantime you might give a try to [PMD](https://pmd.github.io), although it is not too convenient for Android source code.

Comment: Also if you do "Refactor"->"Extract"->"Method" (Cmd+Opt+m), IntelliJ (Android Studio) will automatically help you to replace all the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

with android studio 3.2.1 you can:
Refactor -> Find and replace code Dublicates

Comment: I did not find this option, in Android Studio 2022.1.1

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use sonarqube to find some similar, duplicate code http://androidhubb.blogspot.com/2019/04/sonarqube-android-how-to-use-sonarqube.html
2. 

you can push the repository to githup or gitlab or Bitbucket then use one of these sites to find some similar, duplicate code

*codecy

*codegrip

*codebeat

I  started to use codebeat https://codebeat.co